# How to make interactive option buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

This is what I'm trying to achieve: [buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ji2JO.png).

I can't figure out how to make the buttons contain form data and have only the selected button post to PHP when I click submit.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var count = 0;

function setColor(btn, color) {
  var property = document.getElementById(btn);
  if (count == 0) {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#4d4d4d"
    property.style.color = "#ffffff"
    count = 1;
  } else {
    property.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"
    property.style.color = '#0000ff'
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="button1" onClick="setColor('button1', '#101010')">
  <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="1">1
  <br>
</button>

<button type="button" id="button2" onClick="setColor('button2', '#101010')">
  <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="2">2
  <br>
</button>
```

Also help with resetting the other buttons' colors when I click a new option would be appreciated.

Comment: Do refine your question as it's not really clear.

Comment: @DavidDiao if you can use some JavaScript, then [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39552990/6313073) will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your buttons have an `onclick` listener but the listener is also triggered by events on child elements.
So you can click the button but not the checkbox and it changes its color without modifying the value.

You should use an label instead and with CSS3 you can make it without JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="rooms" />
  <label for="option1">1</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option2" name="rooms" />
  <label for="option2">2</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
  display: none;
}

label{
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  background: #FFF;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
  background: #4d4d4d;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using just a little bit of JavaScript, then the following will be exactly what you need:

**Code:**

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[id^=button]");
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
   button.onclick = function() {        
      /* Remove the 'checked' attribute from the other inputs */
      [].forEach.call(buttons, function(each) {
         if (button !== each) [].forEach.call(each.children, function(child) {
            if (child.nodeName === "INPUT") child.removeAttribute("checked");
         });
      });

      /* Check the child input */
      document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-check")).setAttribute("checked", "");

      /* Remove the 'clicked' attribute from every button */
      [].forEach.call(buttons, function(each) {
         each.removeAttribute("clicked");
      });

      /* Add the 'clicked' attribute to the clicked button */
      this.setAttribute("clicked", "");
   }
});
```

---

**Notes:**

1. In order to get the look you want, the **`input`** itself must be hidden, so we have to use JavaScript to automatically check the **`input`** when the button is clicked.
2. As you can see I have added a **`data-check`** attribute to each button. I did that, in order to avoid having to iterate over each child of each button in order to find the inputs and uncheck them. It basically contains the selector of its **`input`** child, so that we can use it to find the input immediately with **`document.querySelector()`**.

---

Here's a **snippet** demonstrating the solution:

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button[id^=button]");
[].forEach.call(buttons, function(button) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    /* Remove the 'checked' attribute from the other inputs */
    [].forEach.call(buttons, function(each) {
      if (button !== each)[].forEach.call(each.children, function(child) {
        if (child.nodeName === "INPUT") child.removeAttribute("checked");
      });
    });

    /* Check the child input */
    document.querySelector(this.getAttribute("data-check")).setAttribute("checked","");

    /* Remove the 'clicked' attribute from every button */
    [].forEach.call(buttons, function(each) {
      each.removeAttribute("clicked");
    });

    /* Add the 'clicked' attribute to the clicked button */
    this.setAttribute("clicked", "");
  }
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
input[name="rooms"] {
  display: none;
}

button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: dodgerblue;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background-color .3s ease, color .3s ease;
  width: 50px;
}

button[clicked] {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div>
  <p style = "font-size: 1.3em">Rooms</p>
  <div id="button-wrapper">
    <button type="button" id="button1" data-check="[name='rooms'][value='1']" clicked>
      <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="1" checked/><span>1</span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="button2" data-check="[name='rooms'][value='2']">
      <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="2" /><span>2</span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="button2" data-check="[name='rooms'][value='3']">
      <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="3" /><span>3</span>
    </button>

    <button type="button" id="button2" data-check="[name='rooms'][value='4+']">
      <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="4+" /><span>4+</span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```